# How to write a while loop in GAMS

Tags: gams-math

Can anyone help me with this problem please. I want to add to i one by one and put the amount of x(i) equal to 1 in each step, so i wrote it as below but it's not working

```
loop(i,
    x('0')=1;
    t('0')=1;
while(t>m,
      ord(i)=ord(i)+1;
      display i;
      x(i)=1;
      display x;
      t(i)=t(i-1) +1;
   );
 );
```

And by the way m is a variable which is calculated before this, in an equation.

Answer (score 1):

If `m` is a variable from a model that was solved before, you should check its level using the `.l` attribute:

```
...
while(t>m.l,
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [page](https://www.gams.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fgams.doc%2Fuserguides%2Fmccarl%2Fwhile_1.htm) to have a better idea of how to make a **while loop** in GAMS. Also look at this code because it may help you:

```
root=minroot;
*find a sign switch
while(signswitch=0 and root le maxroot,
   root=root+inc;
   function_value2= a-b*root+c*sqr(root);
   if((sign(function_value1) ne sign(function_value2)
      and abs(function_value1) gt 0
      and abs(function_value2) gt tolerance),
         maxroot=root;
         signswitch=1
   else
      if(abs(function_value2) gt tolerance,
         function_value1=function_value2;
         minroot=root;);
      );
*  display 'inside',minroot,maxroot,function_value1,function_value2;
);
```

Comment: Thanks but my problem is the M which is a variable

Comment: Is it impossible to write a while loop based on a variable?